# keycloak - How to create policy to allow Client based on their http request?

Tags: keycloak

I have resource server which has below resource. I want to protect resource based on http request method. If user request with http GET/POST method for the protected resource, Keycloak should grant permission.

http://localhost:8080/jobs

How to achieve this using javascript/Droll based policy.